# Shortcut finding D when diagonalizing a matrix when encountered with a Householder reflection

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

P is given as 
P = $\left(\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & -2\\
1 & -1 & 1
\end{array}\right).$ It is known that P is invertible.

[image: u and H]

I is a 3x3 identity matrix

Supposed to find the diagonal matrix D for H, from which we take the diagonal entries to be our eigenvalues.

With the above of which we see what is given, we can conclude with the possibility of using the relation:
$ HP = PD $

$ P^{-1} HP = D $

Assuming that this is to be solved using pen and paper (without aid of computers), not spending too much time solving (like during an exam) I believe there could be some shortcut that is simpler/shorter than the above triple matrix multiplication. That multiplication involves pretty tedious arithmetical operations involving squareroots, irrational numbers which is timeconsuming and allows very easily for errors to sneak in. I tried doing it, but it seemed like the wrong way to go because of the complexity.

Comment: To be honest, I don't quite understand what you want to do. If you want to find eigenvalues of the matrix, the direct method would be to write down the characteristic polynomial and find its roots. Finding eigenvectors is also not that difficult task. I don't see where a multiplication of matrices defined in your post can become difficult

Comment: Well the matrix D contains the eigenvalues on the diagonal. Now the relation HP = PD is given as hint for this specific problem. Thats why I thought it would be the most straightforward way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $P^{-1}HP = D$, then the columns of $P$ are the eigenvectors of $H$.

So, for every column $p_i$, calculate $Hp_i$ and then use $Hp_i = \lambda_i p_i$ to get the corresponding eigenvalue $\lambda_i$.

So, for the first column you get:
$$\begin{align}
Hp_1 &= (I- 2uu^T)p_1 = p_1 - 2uu^Tp_1 \\
&= \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}
- \frac{2}{3} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \\
&= \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} - \frac{2}{3} \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 3 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ -1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}$$
which gives us that the first eigenvalue is $\lambda_1 = -1$.

This way you don't have to calculate larger matrix products and you don't have to invert $P$.

An even faster way is to see that $H = I - 2uu^T$, for real $u$, is a [Householder reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_transformation) and therefore will have the eigenvalues $\lambda_1 = -1, \lambda_2 = 1, \lambda_3 = 1$.

Comment: Thats exactly what I was after, thanx a bunch! Somehow managed to overlook how simple it was to get rid of the squareroot, just join these constants first, that's an essential part. Good to know this actually has a name.